# Please point out the disadvantage of my git flow

Tags: git-flow

[image]

Hi guys! I'm new to git so this is something that keeps concerning me till now ...

As you guys already knew, below is the most popular git flow. But to me sometimes, I did have some problem with creating new feature branch from develop branch. Because if someone before me, who already committed and merged something bad into develop branch and after that, without knowing I create a new branch base on it, then I will work on a branch with potentially broken, right ?

Then in my new team, I saw a git flow like this:

- Every feature branch is created from master
- When a feature is complete it is merged into the develop branch (testing env)

If tester sees there's no problem with develop branch then:

- A release branch is created from master
- Merge all the completed feature into the release branch. (and test 1 more time on STG env)
- No need to merge back release branch into develop branch. If there's any problem, fix it on feature branch and merge it into develop branch (test again) and if it's ok, merge it into release branch.
- Merge release branch into master.

Doing it this way ensures that every time a new feature branch creates, it have already gone through 2 phase of testing or so I think...

Please give me advice on this one, is it good or not ? Or is there any disadvantage that I dont know. My new team has been working on this git flow for few years and there's no problem until now. But when I suggest it to my friend, they don't like the idea saying that I should have followed the popular one... I'm kinda confused right now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `git-flow` is just a framework. There is no reason why you should not adjust it to your needs.

But there are some disadvantages in creating branches that way:

(1) Your testers might (and most certainly will at some point) still miss a bug which then will end up on `master`. We are all humans and it's simply impossible - no matter how many testers and test phases you have - to produce software that is completely bug-free. `master` is just your new `develop`.

(2) The more important issue here: you always have to wait until new features are on `master` to continue working on them. Often bigger features are split into multiple issue / user stories / whatever to make them easier to work on. You would normally merge part 1 into `develop` (considering it's a shippable feature in itself) and then continue working on this using `develop` as your base.
This is going to be hard (meaning delayed using your `master`-base method).

Comment: A little bit late, but thanks for your answer